# Asus Laptop - A lot messed up when Windows 10 installed

Tags: windows, windows-10, nvidia-geforce

I bought an Asus ROG - G751JYDH71 from Best Buy: [Link](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/asus-rog-17-3-laptop-intel-core-i7-24gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-256gb-solid-state-drive-black/9826256.p?id=1219438695425&skuId=9826256)

I bought this about 2 months ago and it was pre-installed with Windows 8.1. On the 30th I received my free upgrade to Windows 10, which I absolutely love by the way, I ran into a few issues, most of which were resolved in the cumulative patch that was released about half a week later.

There are two outstanding issues that I would consider major, that didn't resolve themselves and I can't find a resolution too.

1. Asus Live Update won't connect anymore. It always throws an error when trying to connect for updates. At first it showed a critical update right after Windows 10 released, but shows no updates found and never connects to check for new ones.
2. My NVidia GeForce experience won't install the latest drivers for Windows 10.  I currently have 353.54. It is telling me I have an update for "Geforce Windows 10 driver" and it's trying to take me to version 353.62. When I try to update it starts initializing the update, and then throws the following message: "Installation Cannot Continue - This NVidia graphics driver is not compatible with this version of Windows. This graphics driver could not find compatible hardware"

Any advice for these two issues would be greatly appreciated. I love this laptop and Windows 10 and I am wanting to get it working well.

Comment: Do you really need Asus Live Update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Windows 10.

Trying to update the NVIDIA Drive to Version 355.82 (WHQL) through GE Force Experience gave the same message: Installation Cannot Continue - This Nvidia graphics driver is not compatible with this version of Windows. This graphics driver could not find compatible hardware"

My unit is an Asus k501-LX with a NVDIA GEFORCE GTX 950M.

I first tried updating through ASUS.

1.) log in to your asus acct. 
2.) Select the product you are trying to update . This will open another window with something like Driver & Tools.
3.) Under OS select Windows 10 
4.) It will Show you a list of files 
5.) DL BIOS 203 (an update for NVIDIA VBIOS) and under BIOS-Utilities DL Windows BIOS Flash Utility.
6.) Install the Utility and use it to flash the BIOS 203.

When i Did this the utility didnt proceed to flash the downloaded bios as the one istalled in my laptop was more updated. (-____-)

So I tried manually searching google for "asus nvidia update for windows 10 gtx 950m". The first result was an update to GEFORCE WINDOWS 10 DRIVER VERSION: 352.84 (WHQL) from the NVIDIA site. I checked the supported products and my 950M was included so, I downloaded and installed the update.

at the end of the installment 2 boxes appeared, the first was an option to create a desktop shortcut, and the second was an option to open the GEFORCE EXPERIENCE program. I only checked the second box. When the NVIDIA Experience opened the update for 355.82 (WHQL) started to download.

I now have the latest version: 355.82 Intsalled.

from this experience i strongly suggest Manually downloading through the NVIDIA site.

Comment: I actually changed my own answer from best answer to yours, because you helped me fix the only issue I had remaining. I appreciate that. I got the live update working, and fixed many other issues. Thank you for your advice about this. Also as a side note for you, I recommend updating to the latest version of BIOS from their website for your laptop. I did that and my BIOS was about 7 versions behind, an I was advised by Asus support to flash the bios. I highly recommend trying to get that to work as it's worth it. More stability and a lot more bios features. Thanks for answering that for me.

Comment: even if the flash utility is telling me that the BIOS initially installed in my laptop is more up to date than the downloaded version from ASUS????

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question, since no-one else has been able to yet.

This is the response I received from their support:

"
I reinstalling ASUS Live Updates from our support site. Here's the link: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win8.1/LiveUpdate/LiveUpdate_Win81_64_VER329.zip

Please copy and paste the link above to download the driver. 
If you are using Google Chrome browser, the file will be downloaded automatically.
If you're using Internet Explorer, you will be prompted to “Open" or "Save" the file, you may save the file to your desktop.

Step 1: Open the file downloaded and look for the “Setup” file, the file type should be an “Application”.
Step 2: Double click on the “Setup” file to run the application. 
Step 3: Once installation has been completed, restart the system.

You can try updating the unit directly from our site. Here's the link: http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS_ROG_G751JY/HelpDesk_Download/
"

Note I simply used the top link to download and install it, and it's working fine again.

Regarding NVidia, I am still researching that. They didn't recommend updating manually since it was an OEM laptop. Once I figure out what's wrong with that and fix it, I Will edit this answer accordingly.